# descending sort makes row disappear

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query where Im trying to find every row and then sort them by a timestamp. It works as intended when I sort it in ascending, but whenever I try to turn it around and sort from descending, the last created row disappear.

```
SELECT * FROM created_teams ORDER BY created DESC
```

I've never seen this behaviour before.

Im using MAMP 4.4.1 with Myphpadmin 4.8.0 and the MYSQL version is 5.6.38.

Comment: So `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM created_teams ORDER BY created DESC` returns the same number when sorted as `ASC`?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, both of them return 33, which is correct..

Comment: What datatype is the `created` column?

Comment: @daniel Timestamp with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default

Comment: Odd. The `ORDER BY` clause is only executed after the query plan has fetched the data from the database, so it shouldn't be able to mutate the results...

Comment: If both queries return 33 rows (and one query contains the missing row), it seems the row is not disappearing, but might just be ordered at the incorrect place (or rather: a place you did not expect). Search for that row manually in the descending result set and check (and post) the content of "created_teams".